# TabLayout Indicator customization

Tags: android, android-tablayout

i have been searching how to change the indicator in Tablayout to be circular, like this
[image]

but i don't know how to do so, any help!

Answer (score 2):

From the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/res/values/styles.xml), the tab indicator is defined as:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="tabMaxWidth">@dimen/design_tab_max_width</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
        <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

and the [tabIndicatorColor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/res/values/attrs.xml) attribute is defined as:

```
<declare-styleable name="TabLayout">
        <attr name="tabIndicatorColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="tabIndicatorHeight" format="dimension"/>
```

so I believe you can't change it to a drawable (shape), you can only change its color.

An alternative is to define a custom view for the tabs and handle the indicator state yourself

Answer (score 0):

1) Create layouts for your tab states(Ex: tab_selected.xml and tab_unselected.xml)

2) Set a custom view for your tabs using your layouts:

```
//get your tab item
TabLayout.Tab tabItem = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
//inflate your layout to a view and set it as the tab's custom view
tabItem.setCustomView(customView);
```

3) Then, using [setOnTabSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener)), keep listening to which tab is selected and update its custom view accordingly(using [setCustomView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setCustomView(android.view.View)))

Comment: Will this provide any animation?

Comment: @user1278890 If you mean like an animation from selected to unselected state, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use custom view for tabs and change it with your TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener