# Customise tab layout

Tags: android, user-interface, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Tab layout is used to create swipe views in android but I was wondering how to customise it. I would like to show a boxed indicator instead of a normal bottom indicator and to place the default value in the middle and just allow the background to change. Something like this

[image: Something like this]

I have seen several tutorials and github projects that allow me to customise the buttons but not the indicator itself.

Does android allow this to do it natively or is there any github repos that can help me?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36061773/5628333) stackoverflow answer

Comment: @ArsenSench I have already looked through that. It allows me to customize the indicator bar in the bottom(like change it into circle and stuff) but if I change that to a box the indicator in the bottom will be in the form of a box but I want the whole text to be enclosed in a box. I think that cannot be done in that.

Comment: theoritically you can make empty tab name , and use layout number inide square as a indicator layout

Comment: @ArsenSench I cannot get what you are saying...

Answer (score 0):

This is how i custom the tabs to my own style.. i iterate every tabs and make any effect e.g : zoom when selected or marquee effect.. you can take a look at this [Custom TabLayout](https://programmingcode4life.blogspot.my/2016/07/custom-tablayout-android.html)

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabs.getChildAt(0);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        View view = vg.getChildAt(j);
        //change drawable for each tabs
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backgroundtabs);

        //if you want to diff drawable for each tabs for example tabs is 4
        //if j == 0    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backgroundtabs1);  
        //if j == 1    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backgroundtabs2);
        //if j == 2    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backgroundtabs3);
        //if j == 3    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backgroundtabs4);

        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) view;
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);

            // Get TextView Element
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
              // change font
              ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(tf);
              // change color
              ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
              // change size
              ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTextSize(18);
              // change padding
              tabViewChild.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
              //..... etc...
            }
        }
    }
```